# Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2 code conversion

Tags: magento2, orders

what will be in Magento 2.2 code of this?

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this for M2

```
protected $order;
public function __construct(

\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,

    ) {


        $this->order = $order;

    }

public function getOrder(){
        $orderId = 10000003;
        $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

}
```

Or

```
protected $orderFactory;
public function __construct(

        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,

    ) {


        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;

    }

public function getOrder(){
        $orderId = 10000003;
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

}
```

Comment: If you pass order to constructor two times per request - it will be shared. It's not expected behavior. So I can't recommend to use first variant, second is better, but correct one - load via repository.

Answer (score 2):

use Magento Order factory Class.

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
```

First, you have to inject this class to `__construct()`of your class where you want to use.

Then you can get order details using factory class  below code:

```
protected $orderFactory;
public function __construct(
....
 \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
.....
)
{
  $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}

public function getOrderBYIncrementId()
{ 
  $orderIncrementID = 10000250;
  $orderModel = $this->orderFactory->create();
   $orderModel->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementID);   
}
```

Comment: It's kind of Magento 1 style used in Magento 2. Correct one - use repository for getting order

Comment: ihor donot think the factory is wrong. Chosen between repository and factory is user call

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class BlockName extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getOrderById($id) {
        return $this->orderRepository->get($id);
    }

    public function getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId) {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('increment_id', $incrementId);

        $order = $this->orderRepository->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems();

        return $order;
    }
}
```